# Calculate topic frequency given word probabilities, over thousands of topics and millions of Tweets

Tags: r, twitter, probability, lda, topic-modeling

I have Tweet data that looks essentially like this

```
userID <- c("1","2","2")
text <- c("cat dog", "this is a fish tweet", "this tweet contains a topic")
testDF <- data.frame(userID, text)
```

I have a list of 2000 topics (obtained from http://wwbp.org/data.html) each with words and the respective conditional probability. It looks like this, with 0 and 1 being topics. Also, topics 0 and 1 can have overlapping words, but likely with different probabilities.

[image: topics]

For simplicity, this is an example topic df

```
term <- c("dog", "cat", "fish", "food")
topic <- c("pet","pet","pet","pet")
prob <- c(.84, .74, .44, .03)
testDF2 <- data.frame(term, topic, prob)
```

I need to get the topic probability for each tweet, and the calculation is shown below.[image]

Desired end result: a way to see which topics each userID talks most about, but since I have 2000 topics does that mean I have to loop through all 2000, resulting in an additional 2000 columns with probabilities for each? I am not sure how to approach this, as my dataset has 1 million tweets.

My current thoughts: a loop through each word for each tweet, looking up in the topic table, and doing the calculation. However, this would result in 2000 columns and likely too much compute time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From what you provided, it doesn't look like there's enough information to calculate what you're looking for. However, if you are calculating LDA from one of the many popular topic modeling packages there will be enough info. Could you provide a small reproducible example of going from raw text to your model? something like the below using textmineR. (Also can work with topicmodels, lda, text2vec, etc.)
```
library(textmineR)

dtm <- CreateDtm(mydocs) # where mydocs is a character vector

lda <- FitLdaModel(dtm, k = 10, iterations = 100)
```

Comment: To be more succinct: you've got P(token|topic) but to do the calculation you want (correctly), you need P(topic|token). To get the latter, you need P(topic|document) and P(token) from the original training corpus and model.